# SLF4J no providers were found when running integration-tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback, slf4j

I have project using Spring boot and having three distinct sourceSets (main, test and integration test). The integration-test source set is defined that way in the respective Gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir "$buildDir/generated/server/src/main/java"
        }
    }
    integrationTest {
        java {
            compileClasspath += main.output + test.output
            runtimeClasspath += main.output + test.output
            srcDir 'src/integration-test/java'
        }
        resources.srcDir 'src/integration-test/resources'
    }
}
```

The problem that I am facing is that when I run the integration-tests suite, the application starts but nothing gets logged. In fact I am getting the following warning:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/Users/akourtesas/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/1.2.11/4741689214e9d1e8408b206506cbe76d1c6a7d60/logback-classic-1.2.11.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
```

I have tried debugging this but I have no idea what's happening. I have printed the classpaths for both the `main` and `integrationTest` source sets and I can for sure say that the SLF4J version is 1.7.36 and my Logback version is 1.2.11. I have no custom configuration or anyting weird in place so it seems all the more weird that this works fine in all cases except the integration tests. For reference my Spring Boot version is 2.7.5.

Has anyone encountered this in the past? If yes what needs to be done in order to resolve this?

Comment: Are you using Wiremock 2.34.0 by any chance? Then upgrade to 2.35.0. We had the same issue and updated to 2.34.0 just a day before 2.35.0 was released. Reason: wiremock-jre8-standalone:2.34.0 includes version 2.x of slf4j-api in their jar, so it doesn't show up in any dependency tree. See https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/issues/1964

Comment: You are a life saver! Can you please add this as an answer so I can upvote it please?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using gradle, add this dependency

```
implementation 'org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j2-impl:2.20.0'
```